# Theoretic (QED) Atomic Ionization Energies Database?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, ionization-energy, databases

The 2019 paper "[QED tests with highly-charged ions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06274)" contains a survey of QED-calculated atomic ionization energies.  I can manually copy the values of interest therein, but it seem that theoreticians attempting to improve on algorithms used to calculate such things would benefit from a benchmark or gold standard database.  Does such a database exist?

Comment: Might the NIST database be of use to you ? https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/ionEnergy.html

Comment: By "gold standard" I meant as a calculation gold standard -- in other words, QED-calculated figures, while they may not be the "gold standard" in the absolute (empirical) sense, they are in the sense that other algorithms should approach the QED-calculated figures and attempt to do so with fewer compute resources.